# How To Create Automated Backup Files In Vb.Net Application?

Tags: vb.net

How to create automated backup files  and backup type compress.
But I want to backup the folder containing Data Files (.doc,.xls,.tiff,.pdf...) but not sql database.
I Want file Backup SHARE-AC.zip. But now have get folder SHARE-AC don't zip.

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.IO.Compression
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        Dim dstr As String
        Dim mstr As String
        Dim ystr As String
        Dim folstr As String
        Dim dsumstr As String

        dstr = DateTime.Today.ToString("dd")
        mstr = DateTime.Today.ToString("MM")
        ystr = DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyy")
        dsumstr = ystr & "-" & mstr & "-" & dstr
        folstr = "Y:\server1\Fileserver-" & dsumstr
        Try
            My.Computer.FileSystem.CreateDirectory(folstr)

            My.Computer.FileSystem.CreateDirectory(folstr & "\SHARE-AC")
            My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyDirectory("D:\SHARE-AC", folstr & "\SHARE-AC")



            Label1.Text = "Back up DATE   " & dsumstr & "  Complete"
        Catch ex As Exception
            Label1.Text = (ex.Message)
        End Try

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Me.Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: you have problem with zipping file? your question is not clear at all

Comment: I want to backup the data to other drive. And wanted a backup folder with compressed data.
but now i have folder backup but don't compressed
How to edit code ?

Answer (score 0):

i dont get your question but If you just wanna zip your file you can use [this](http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sharpziplib/)

**Update** : You could use GZipStream in the System.IO.Compression namespace

.NET 2.0.

```
Public Shared Sub CompressFile(path As String)
Dim sourceFile As FileStream = File.OpenRead(path)
Dim destinationFile As FileStream = File.Create(path & ".gz")

Dim buffer As Byte() = New Byte(sourceFile.Length - 1) {}
sourceFile.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)

Using output As New GZipStream(destinationFile, CompressionMode.Compress)
    Console.WriteLine("Compressing {0} to {1}.",sourceFile.Name,destinationFile.Name, False)

    output.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
End Using

' Close the files.
sourceFile.Close()
destinationFile.Close()
 End Sub
```

.NET 4

```
Public Shared Sub Compress(fi As FileInfo)
' Get the stream of the source file.
Using inFile As FileStream = fi.OpenRead()
    ' Prevent compressing hidden and 
    ' already compressed files.
    If (File.GetAttributes(fi.FullName) And FileAttributes.Hidden) <> FileAttributes.Hidden And fi.Extension <> ".gz" Then
        ' Create the compressed file.
        Using outFile As FileStream = File.Create(Convert.ToString(fi.FullName) & ".gz")
            Using Compress As New GZipStream(outFile, CompressionMode.Compress)
                ' Copy the source file into 
                ' the compression stream.
                inFile.CopyTo(Compress)

                Console.WriteLine("Compressed {0} from {1} to {2} bytes.", fi.Name, fi.Length.ToString(), outFile.Length.ToString())
            End Using
        End Using
    End If
End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: I want to backup the data to other drive. And wanted a backup folder with compressed data. but now i have folder backup but don't compressed .How to edit code ?

Comment: For compressing you should use some library like the one i told you , it very simple

Answer (score 0):

if you want to zip the file on the directory you set use this code :

```
    Dim dstr As String
    Dim mstr As String
    Dim ystr As String
    Dim folstr As String
    Dim dsumstr As String

    dstr = DateTime.Today.ToString("dd")
    mstr = DateTime.Today.ToString("MM")
    ystr = DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyy")
    dsumstr = ystr & "-" & mstr & "-" & dstr
    folstr = "Y:\server1\Fileserver-" & dsumstr
    Try
        My.Computer.FileSystem.CreateDirectory(folstr)

        My.Computer.FileSystem.CreateDirectory(folstr & "\SHARE-AC")
        ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory("D:\SHARE-AC", folstr & "\SHARE-AC\myfile.zip") ' Zip all file in your directory
        'My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyDirectory("D:\SHARE-AC", folstr & "\SHARE-AC")



        Label1.Text = "Back up DATE   " & dsumstr & "  Complete"
    Catch ex As Exception
        Label1.Text = (ex.Message)
    End Try

End Sub
```

YOU NEED TO IMPORT:

```
 Imports System.IO
 Imports System.IO.Compression
```

**UPDATE**

You can use [SharpZipLip](http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sharpziplib/)
And here some [Examples](https://github.com/icsharpcode/SharpZipLib/wiki/Zip-Samples).

Comment: Zip file in 4.5 freamwork, why you use vs 2012 with old framework?

Comment: then you have to use third party library like  [DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/) OR USE 4.5 FRAMEWORK

Comment: Error . The method or operation is not implemented.

Comment: I config target 4.5 framework and new project but error  The method or operation is not implemented.

Comment: Add `System.IO.Compression.FileSystem ` Reference To your project.